# How to install DE from Ubuntu 17.10 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, 17.10

How to install the Gnome session from 17.10 (with all customizations) to Ubuntu 16.04. Unity became very buggy on 16.04 so I would like to try the customized Gnome from 17.10, since I use my computer as workstation I would like to use 16.04 for some time until 18.04 becomes stable enough.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will not be able to install the gnome session of 17.10 as such on Ubuntu 16.04, especially as you indicate valuing stability. However, you can rather quickly mimic the 17.10 desktop on your 16.04 by installing gnome and two gnome extensions, dash to dock and KStatusNotifierItem/AppIndicator. Then configure dash to dock to have it appear as a panel on the left. The dock in Ubuntu 17.10 is actually a fork of Dash to dock, where the customization options have been limited or concealed.

A less "stable" solution would be to add PPA for a more recent gnome shell version. However, it may not be worth it. With a three-week wait, you will be able to install the 18.04 release candidate, which will update itself to the release version within a week.